# Mounted image not found in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am mounting an executable file within my container using docker-compose:

```
volumes:
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
```

When I connect to my container, I can clearly see that the file has been correctly mounted.
Though, when I try to execute it, I have a weird issue:

```
/app # ls -l /usr/bin/ | grep docker
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      60586560 Mar  7 15:57 docker
/app # /usr/bin/docker ps
sh: /usr/bin/docker: not found
```

If you have any clue about this issue, please let me know.

Best regards.

Comment: This could be caused by missing shared libraries or other incompatibilities; running an Ubuntu-based `docker` binary on an Alpine container, or using an Ubuntu 22.04 binary in an Ubuntu 18.04 image, or even bind-mounting a MacOS binary into a Linux container.  You should `RUN` an installation step in your Dockerfile to install a compatible `docker` binary rather than trying to inject it from the host.

Comment: Thx @DavidMaze ! This was the problem, my docker container was not based on ubuntu like my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was given to me in the comments above. The problem was that my docker image was not based on ubuntu like my server, causing dependencies issues.